# Prevent cookies being reused after user is logged out (Symfony 2.6)

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.6

I'm running a Symfony 2.6 application that uses the FOSUserBundle. When users log in they are always 'remembered' because I've configured these settings in my security.yml:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/remember_me.html

Security.yml:

```
 remember_me:
      key: "%secret%"
      lifetime: 604800 # One week
      path: /
      domain: ~
      always_remember_me: true
      secure: true
```

This creates a REMEMBERME cookie when the user logs in; that's all working fine. However, when I store the cookies (For e.g. by using EditThisCookie in Google Chrome), I can still re-use these cookies after the user has logged out.

My scenerio:
- User logs in
- Copy REMEMBERME cookie
- User logs out
- Paste REMEMBERME cookie and refresh the page
- The user is logged in again (which I do not want!)

How can I prevent these cookies from being used again after the user has logged out?

Answer (score 1):

The REMEMBERME cookie is not used to restore an existing session, but to **login** again the user. So of course you can login again with the cookie after you've been logged out, else what would be the purpose of REMEMBERME? In other words, that's expected behaviour.

Anyway you can add a "Logout" event listener that deletes the cookie.

http://api.symfony.com/2.5/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/LogoutListener.html

I can't reccomend a specific tutorial about that but you can find tons of informations on the net. If you don't find enough, add a new specific question on how to implement a logout handler.